# Is there a way to force visa revocation?

Tags: visas

My dad got a US visa a few months back and has recently visited. He has grown old, and not in a good health too. Now he is planning to visit again but we (family member) have to stop him.

We are afraid that travelling again would make matters worse. Honestly, we cannot directly resist him to travel as he won't stop like that. So, we are looking for a way to stop him without letting him know. I suspect that getting his visa revoked somehow would stop him.

Is there any way that we could force his visa to be revoked? Or is there any other way to stop him?

Comment: You should solve the problem with him. Do he has friends or some people at home to convince him not to travel. And do you really know why he want to travel (it would be difficult to him)? Maybe try to tackle such part. If he feel alone: increase phone and video calls (and possibly visit to him and common holidays). Authorities are already too invasive, do not increase that!

Comment: You should not try to do this behind his back. If his health is bad, maybe he wants to travel to see you and his family while he still can. Are you all able to visit him instead? Is he still able to get health insurance when he travels (if no, that would be a big worry, and a good reason for him not to travel). In any event, you should talk to him about your concerns. As far as getting his visa revoked, I doubt you can do that without him being involved unless you have a Power of Attorney or similar legal right to act on his behalf.

Comment: This question might be better-placed on [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm sure there are lots of things you could try, but most would be more stressful for your father than flying.

Comment: No, there's no way of revoking one's own visa, let alone someone else's. You can hide his passport, though.